# Calculador de porcentagem em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, matemática

Estou usando o seguinte código:

```
<script>
    function calcValor() {

        //Zera o campo total
        document.getElementById("CAMPO_78").value;

        //Declarando a variavel
        let preco, porcentagem, desconto, novopreco;

        //Obtendo dados atraves do prompt
        preco = parseFloat(document.getElementById("CAMPO_75").value);
        porcentagem = parseFloat(document.getElementById("CAMPO_85").value);

        if (isNaN(preco));
        //Realizando os calculos
        desconto = preco * porcentagem / 100;
        novopreco = preco - desconto;

        if (isNaN(novopreco));
        //O .toFixed(2) faz com que o valor seja corrijdo para duas casas decimais
        //document.write("O preço com desconto é R$ " + novopreco.toFixed(2) + "!!!");
        document.getElementById("CAMPO_78").value = 'R$ ' + novopreco;
    } 
</script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="a3label control-label" for="CAMPO_75">Valor da Mensalidade</label> 
        <input class="a3formcontrol form-control money" data-campo-id="@@75@@" data-nome="75 - Mensalidade" data-tipo-documental-id="3" id="CAMPO_75" onfocus="calcValor()" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="a3label control-label" for="CAMPO_76">Bolsa (%)</label> 
        <input class="a3formcontrol form-control" data-campo-id="@@85@@" data-nome="85 - Bolsa (%)" data-tipo-documental-id="3" id="CAMPO_85" type="text" onfocus="calcValor()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

O cálculo é feita da forma correta, porém em certas situações, como essa abaixo:

[image: Imagem]

Ele acaba arredondando pra um valor inteiro. E quando eu coloco uma para mudar o `number` da variável porcentagem, ela não altera, porém quando substituo o `.` por `,` consigo o resultado.

Alguém já passou por isso e pode me ajudar ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que acontece é que você está trabalhando com string e não com um número real, para trabalhar com número decimal que contém virgula é preciso transformar ele para decimal no formato padrão computacional que seria a divisão do decimal por ponto (.).

No seu caso, não basta usar a função `parseFloat()`, você precisa trocar as virgulas por ponto, usando a função de `replace()`.

#### Exemplo:

- Nesse caso a função `parseFloat()` recuperou a string e transformou em numero, ou seja, "90,55" não é um numero real, a função por si própria, reconheceu apenas o 90 como um número e ignorou o ",55".

  ```
  let value = "90,55";
  parseFloat(value); 
  // retorno = 90
  ```

#### Solução

```
let value = "90,55";
value = value.replace(",", ".");
parseFloat(value.replace); 
// retorno = 90.55
```

- Nesse caso, o que foi feito ? Foi dado o valor "90,55" pelo usuário, em seguida foi feito uma troca de caracter na string com a função `replace()`, foi trocado a virgula por ponto, com isso transformei a string para "90.55", que é formato ideal para ser usado como parâmetro na função `parseFloat()`.

---

- Caso utilize separador de milhar também recomendo utilizar essa forma no `replace()` - `value.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".")` - primeiro remove o separador de milhar(.) para não dar problema na casa decimal e em seguida troca a virgula por ponto.

  ```
  let value = "2.315,80";
  value = value.replace(".", "").replace(",", ".");
  parseFloat(value.replace); 
  // retorno = 2315.80
  ```