# Calculo de porcentagem em javascript

Tags: javascript, matemática

Olá!

Estou com uma dúvida daquelas sobre um código de calculo de desconto no javascript, abaixo segue o código

JS

```
function ValorMensal () {
    var mensalidade, desconto, descontofinal, precofinal;
    mensalidade = parseFloat(document.getElementById("CAMPO_27").value);
    desconto = parseFloat(document.getElementById("CAMPO_25").value);
    descontofinal = mensalidade * desconto / 100;
    precofinal = mensalidade - descontofinal;
    document.getElementById("CAMPO_18").value = precofinal;
}
```

O que acontece, tenho 2﻿ problemas, que estou a quase 3 semanas e não consigo resolver

Quando jogo somente o valor do campo mensalidade, ele deveria teoricamente aparecer no campo mensalidad﻿e final, independente ou não de haver desconto, porém para minha surpresa ele aparece exatamente igual a imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E minha outra dúvida é sobre a questão de "," e "."

Quando calculo desconto com , por exemplo. 2314,50, ele arredonda e quando coloco 2314.50, ele me da o valor exato. Alguém pode me dar uma luz? Desde já fico agredecido

Comment: Uma luz: `parseFloat('')` retorna `NaN`.

Comment: Acho que sua resposta está aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/437716/119788

Comment: Os cálculos devem ser feitos utilizando ```.``` para os números. Pra isso você pode fazer um ```parseFloat(document.getElementById("CAMPO_25").value.replace(',', '.'))```.  
Você vai precisar fazer um ```if``` para verificar se o valor de desconto é maior que 0, caso contrário ele não vai fazer a lógica pra aplicar o desconto. Já que o valor de desconto será 0 caso o usuário não preencha, e isso fará seu valor final também ficar 0 após a multiplcação.
Outra boa prática é utilizar nomes mais significativos para os campos, como "desconto", "mensalidade" ou algo do tipo ao invés de "CAMPO_X".